# Meaning of "the hell he is"

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

I was watching Harry Potter movie. Harry tells a truth to everyone.

Hearing this, another character says that Harry (main character) is lying (i.e., not telling the truth). One more character says immediately after that: "The hell he is!".

Now I don't understand the meaning of "The hell he is!".

It either means he is telling truth or he isn't. But not sure which one of is it.

I turned on Hindi dubbed audio (Hindi is my native language) which clearly said like: "He is NOT lying".

Then to further confirm, I turned on Hindi subtitles. Again, it was contradictory to dubbed audio. It read like: He is lying.

So now I'm confused. Any idea what can it mean?

Comment: Related: [Definition 2](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/like_hell); [Definition 4](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/like%20hell); [Definition 1](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/like-hell); [Definition 2](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/like+hell); [Definition 2](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/like--hell).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The audio is right and the subtitles are wrong. Further, the expression works with or without a final verb.

"**The hell he is**." = "He's not." (with reference to whatever  was just said)

"**The hell he's lying.**" = "He's not lying."

It's an expression that simply adds emphasis.  It makes no literal sense in any way I can conceive of.

A related slightly off-color expression:

"My ass." = "That's not true." (again, the reference is to whatever was just said)

"My ass you can bench 200 pounds." = "No way you can bench 200 pounds."

Comment: And here are a couple of dictionary definitions to corroborate this (2nd meaning in each case):
https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+hell
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/the%20hell

Comment: I think the literal sense is that *only in hell would that happen*. Just as hell is a negative place that we reject, the predicate is being denied.

Comment: Archetypal example:  John Wayne - '[The hell I won't](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o3343LUHNb4&t=90s)'

Comment: The accepted answer gets a correct interpretation for the case in question but is a bit questionable.  Basically in English there are a number of swear words, which when used in front of "are / is / can" will negate the meaning.  While it adds emphasis, it doesn't "simply" do that as it also negates.  "The hell" + "he is" = "His is not" (but with more emphasis and clearly somewhat slang/crude language).

Comment: @Robert That also has difficulties. "The hell you will." meaning you're not going to vs "No shit you will." meaning you're definitely going to...